# Different rounding between assignment and printf

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a program with two variables of type int.

```
int num;
int other_num;

/* change the values of num and other_num with conditional increments */

printf ("result = %f\n", (float) num / other_num);

float r = (float) num / other_num;
printf ("result = %f\n", r);
```

The value written in the first printf is different from the value written by the second printf (by 0.000001, when printed with 6 decimal places).

Before the division, the values are:

```
num = 10201 
other_num = 2282
```

I've printed the resulting numbers to 15 decimal places. Those numbers diverge in the 7th decimal place which explains the difference in the 6th one.

Here are the numbers with 15 decimal places:

```
4.470201577563540
4.470201492309570
```

I'm aware of floating point rounding issues, but I was expecting the calculated result to be the same when performed in the assignment and in the printf argument.

Why is this expectation incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: They match here in a quick test I just made.  What are the values of `num` and `other_num`?  What environment are you using (host architecture, compiler version, etc.)?

Comment: I edit the question and provided the numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is something other than 0 on your system.

In the first case, the expression `(float) num / other_num` has nominal type `float`, but is possibly evaluated at higher precision (if you're on x86, probably `long double`). It's then converted to `double` for passing to `printf`.

In the second case, you assign the result to a variable of type `float`, which forces dropping of excess precision. The `float` is then promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

Of course without actual numbers, this is all just guesswork. If you want a more definitive answer, provide complete details on your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. I tried declaring the r variable as a double, and both prints started yelding the same value as the printf call. This is coherent with what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The point is the actual position of the result of the expressions during the execution of the program. C values can live on the memory (which includes caches) or just on registers if the compiler decides that this kind of optimization is possible in the specific case.

In the first printf, the expression result is stored in a register, as the value is just used in the same C instruction, so the compiler thinks (correctly), that it would be useless to store it somewhere less volatile; as result, the value is stored as double or long double depending on the architecture.

In the second case, the compiler did not perform such optimization: the value is stored in a variable within the stack, which is memory, not register; the same value is therefore chopped at the 23th significant bit.

More examples are [provided by streflop](http://nicolas.brodu.net/en/programmation/streflop/) and its documentation.